# Where is the log file located in OTRS

Tags: otrs

During an investigation on timeouts that occurred in OTRS I was looking for the log files. Logs like Access Logs - HTTP request response timestamps or Error logs. Where do I find relevant logs?

I found one log file though it is not very relevant `/data/mysql/care-bin.2132`

OTRS Version: OTRS 6.0 Community Edition

Comment: I found this on OTRS site https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/8.0/en/content/administration/system-log.html Is this the only log available?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for error in your apache log or in your otrs directory under `var/log/`.
It may also be, that the log file is changed, so take a look at the system configuration for the setting name `LogModule::LogFile`.